# zend model using helpers

Tags: php, zend-framework

Call to undefined method Application_Model_Users::_helper()

how can i get the redirect helper to work in models?  in works in the controllers that extends the zend controller action but not in models

thanks

Comment: Why would you do that? I don’t think models are part of the dispatch chain, neither you should force them to be.

Comment: You should only call the redirect helper from your controller layer, since the model layer is intended only for data handling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either fetch it from the within the model:

```
$redirector = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('redirector');
```

or fetch the helper in the controller and inject it to the model, which would be somewhat cleaner:

```
$redirector = $this->_helper->getHelper('redirector');
$userModel = new Application_Model_Users($redirector);
```

## But …

… like it was already pointed out in the comments - **nothing** in the Model should be responsible for redirecting a request, so I strongly suggest you dont do this in the Model at all. Keep this in the controller.